# How to know which sub-view was clicked when onClick callback function was called?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

In my design, there is a view that contains many sub-views. I set a onClickListener object with onClick(View v) method to the view instance. I just found that no matter which sub-view was clicked, the v.getId() was always the id of root view but not the id of clicked sub-view?

Is there any way to know which sub-view was clicked ? I expected to get some useful information from the View object passed by onClick, but got nothing useful from the public method of View class.

Comment: Add your code snippet for more information.

Comment: can you post your xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. If your view has OnClickListener, it means that view responds to click event, not its subviews. You should set OnClickListener's on each view if you want to know, which view was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Add these methods to your custom view class

```
fun setOnFirstSubViewListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    firstSubView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.invoke()
    }
}

fun setOnSecondSubViewListener(listener: () -> Unit) {
    secondSubView.setOnClickListener {
        listener.invoke()
    }
}
//and so on..
```

Then from whenever you need you can call this:

```
myCoolAndComplicatedView.setOnFirstSubViewListener {
    //do smth
}

myCoolAndComplicatedView.setOnSecondSubViewListener {
    //do smth
}
//and so on...
```